# Docker swarm in connecting two different PC

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-swarm

I have two different machines . One machine have ubuntu as host OS and other machine have ubuntu installed in virtual box  . I have create swarm manager on first machine which have ubuntu as host OS but the problem is second machine which have ubuntu inside virtual box is  unable to connect with that manager . I am getting this error on worker machine

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 14 desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable
```

I am using `Bridged Adapter` setting on my virtual box so that ubuntu on vm get similar ip address as of host . Can anyone help me how to create swarm network on such hierarchy.

Comment: what command are you using to connect to the manager from the other host?

Comment: @omu_negru I am using this command to join manager `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-442fc9b90vfz73i19klzxwifvp5buxasu6okg8cauolrffbpee-87eh7kg9nt3x1hiarb0r62v40 192.168.1.102:2377`  . Is this problem with virtual box ?

Comment: can you ping that particular ip from virtualbox?

Comment: Yes I can ping that computer ip from my virtualbox

Comment: What is the output of `sudo iptables -S` on both the OS? Add the output to your question

Comment: what about `nmap -p 2377 192.168.1.102` from inside the virtualbox

Comment: @TarunLalwani Here is an output of `sudo iptables -S` command https://gist.github.com/mohammadobaid1/c77ffe1bc0533d48b6ab3ae1c31e13fb

Comment: This is from which machine? I need from both machines